# Is Anilingus healthy?

Tags: sex

Some animals do Anilingus, so it might be  reasonable to think that also among healthy humans anilingus might be without harm or is even healthy to strengthen the immune system or has some other benefits. Is that true when done on a regular basis from a young age on like some animals do, that it is healthy?

Comment: You were asking a lot of questions, which made it far too broad. I edited it down to one question since it would have been closed as too broad otherwise. You can pose the others as separate questions if you wish.

Comment: Isn't there a potential risk of hepatitis here?

Answer (score 3):

According to Jack Morin, the author of

> [Anal Pleasure and Health: A Guide for Men, Women and Couples](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Anal-Pleasure-Health-Guide-Couples/dp/0940208377)

[anilingus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anilingus) can actually be beneficial (point 10 of '[10 Rules of Anal Sex](https://www.scribd.com/doc/86887/10-Rules-of-Anal-Sex-by-Jack-Morin)').

> 10. Anal sex can be perfectly safe, even beneficial.
>       The taboo against anal eroticism is perpetuated by the almost universal belief among physicians that anal sex is inevitably dangerous. No physical injury from anal stimulation results if both partners refuse to tolerate pain, never use force and
>       avoid the use of drugs.
>       . . .
>       Thousands of men and women with chronic anal medical problems have
>       restored their anal health by challenging their
>       negative attitudes. This approach is indispensable for full erotic
>       enjoyment of the anus.

But most references claim (e.g. the Wikipedia link above) claim that it is very hazardous to your health.

An audio excerpt from this book is available from:

> https://www.audible.co.uk/pd/Anal-Pleasure-and-Health-Audiobook/B009152MHY

in which the narrator describes only how to avoid 'anal hell', and does not mention any positive medical advantages.

Comment: That's mostly a statement, less argument & explanation. What health problems and 'why/how' could be addressed by overcoming "negative attitudes"? (Quality of ref-source aside, I read that mostly as 'new source of potential pleasure ie emotional gratification. Anything else?

Comment: @LangLangC; I'm not a fan of it myself, so I can't supply positive-type arguments. I think it readily leads to disease, but JM disagrees, in part at least.

Comment: That's not what I ask of you ;) Even normal intercourse *can* lead to STDs and other nasties, but barriers diminish the risk as does 'all involved known 'healthy''. Has JM or anyone an argument for anything else but 'more pleasure' (aka minor supporting reasons, which are presumably the main reasons OP asks for) – since normal intercourse is generally seen as 'healthy', medically above 'mere pleasure', although *that* is a large part of it?

Comment: @LangLangC; I don't think he can find any. I've added an audio link in which he completely avoids mentioning any actual gains from [anal sex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anal_sex) - which is illegal in some countries BTW..